# ¿Cómo puedo generar un archivo ZIP con PHP 7?

Tags: php7

Estoy intentando generar un archivo ZIP para descargar una serie de documentos guardados en unas carpetas. Son bastantes documentos, así que no puedo permitir que se descargue uno por uno. He intentado con este código:

```
<?php

/**
 * 
 */
class ZIP{

    function validarZIP($ficha, $programa, $hoy){

        //creamos una instancia de ZipArchive
        $zip = new ZipArchive();

        /*directorio a comprimir
         * la barra inclinada al final es importante
         * la ruta debe ser relativa no absoluta
         */
        $dir = '../archivos/paquetes/' . $ficha . " - " . $programa . " - " . $hoy . "/";

        //ruta donde guardar los archivos zip, ya debe existir
        $rutaFinal = "../archivos/creados";

        if(!file_exists($rutaFinal)){

            mkdir($rutaFinal);

        }

        $archivoZip = $ficha . " - " . $programa . " - " . $hoy . ".zip";

        if ($zip->open($archivoZip, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) === true) {

            $this->agregar_zip($dir, $zip);

            $zip->close();

            if (file_exists($rutaFinal. "/" . $archivoZip)) {

                echo "Proceso Finalizado!! <br/><br/>

                Descargar: <a href='$rutaFinal/$archivoZip'>$archivoZip</a>";

            } else {

                echo "Error, archivo zip no ha sido creado!!";

            }

        }

    }

    function agregar_zip($dir, $zip) {

        if (is_dir($dir)) {

            if ($da = opendir($dir)) {

                while (($archivo = readdir($da)) !== false) {

                    if (is_dir($dir . $archivo) && $archivo != "." && $archivo != "..") {

                        echo "<strong>Creando directorio: $dir$archivo</strong><br/>";
                        $this->agregar_zip($dir . $archivo . "/", $zip);

                    } elseif (is_file($dir . $archivo) && $archivo != "." && $archivo != "..") {

                        echo "Agregando archivo: $dir$archivo <br/>";
                        $zip->addFile($dir . $archivo, $dir . $archivo);

                    }

                }

                closedir($da);

            }

        }

    }

}

?>
```

Este código debería dejarme crear el ZIP. El problema, es que no me lo genera. Al final, me muestra que está creando el archivo y me arroja el error de que no se ha podido generar el ZIP.

Quisiera saber cómo podría hacer que me genere el archivo de forma más fácil para poder descargarlo.

Agradecería mucho cualquier ayuda, por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El zip que creas no es el que verificas con `file_exists()`. La diferencia es `$rutaFinal`.

Adicionalmente te puedes ahorrar la función recursiva de directorios:

```
        $zip = new ZipArchive();

        $rutaOrigen = '../archivos/paquetes/';
        $nombre     = "$ficha - $programa  - $hoy";
        $rutaFinal  = "../archivos/creados/";

        if(!file_exists($rutaFinal))
            mkdir($rutaFinal);

        if( $zip->open( $rutaFinal.$nombre.'.zip', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) === true) {

            $rdi = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $rutaOrigen.$nombre );
            $rii = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $rdi );
            foreach( $rii as $archivo )
                if( $archivo->isFile() ) 
                    $zip->addFile( $archivo->getPathname() );

            $zip->close();

        }

        if( file_exists( $rutaFinal.$nombre.'.zip' ) ){

            echo "Proceso Finalizado!! <br/><br/>
            Descargar: <a href='$rutaFinal/$archivoZip'>$archivoZip</a>";

        } else {

            echo "Error, archivo zip no ha sido creado!!";

        }
```

Comment: como detalle, en esta solucion puede darte errores el mkdir porque no se pueda crear la estructura de carpeta. Es recomendable comprobar el resultado de mkdir. Se podria mirar el resultado de `mkdir($rutaFinal, 0777, true)`  para verificar que se ha podido crear toda la estructura de directorios que se pide en $rutaFinal